# Map for Microsoft's Spatial Data

Tags: sql-server, bing-maps, spatial

1. What kind of map does Microsoft's spatial data use? I heard that
   the spatial's data is based on x, y coordination for GPS?
2. Is is possible to use Microsoft's spatial data for Bing's map?

Comment: Please provide more information or close this question.  What do you mean, "Microsoft's spatial data"?  SQL Server spatial geography data types?  Microsoft's HR team?  Microsoft's Bing API?

Answer (score 1):

The Bing Spatial Data Services in Bing Maps, and all other map controls and services in Bing Maps use a Spherical Mercator projection in decimal degrees. The WGS84 project system is used by GPS devices and aligns very accurately in Bing Maps.

If you are instead asking about spatial data in SQL Server, SQL supports a large number of projection types. The SRID value 4326, is the most commonly used for GPS data and Bing Maps.